# how to get the regular expression

Tags: c#-4.0, expression

i want to remove the google ad html in the text,such as

```
xxxxxxx<div class="gg200x300" style="padding: 19px; margin: 0px 22px 0px 0px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; float: left; border: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229); color: rgb(37, 37, 37); font-family: 宋体, sans-serif;"><iframe src="http://g.163.com/r?site=netease&amp;affiliate=news&amp;cat=article&amp;type=logo300x250&amp;location=13" width="300" height="250" frameborder="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>yyyyyy
```

i want to remove the html between xxxxxxx and yyyyyy, and return

```
xxxxxxxyyyyyy
```

how to set regular expression using c# and could you please describe why use the regular expression ?
thanks.

Comment: what kind of content is around the add?

Comment: remove <div .......<iframe .......</iframe></div>

Comment: <div.*<iframe.*</iframe></div>

Comment: [Regex is not a parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Answer (score 0):

If it is always in the `div`, you can do something like this.

```
if (a.IndexOf("<div") > 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine(a.Remove(a.IndexOf("<div"),a.IndexOf("</div>")-1)); 
   //output xxxxxxxyyyyyy
}
```

It is not the complete answer, but at least get you going.
I'm not so good with Regex, but my hunch is that it'll tough to develop Regex for this string. 
Hope this will help.

**EDIT**

To make life easier wrap that `div` in another `div`. Like

```
<div id="googleadd">.......</div>
```

Then search based on that.

```
 if (a.IndexOf("<div id='googleadd'>") > 0)
 {
  :
  :
 }
```

Than you know exactly what you're deleting.

Comment: This needs more filtering. The code, as it stands, will remove any div element.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the same class, it would be very easy to use @gmail user's method but changed to this:

```
if (a.IndexOf("<div") > 0)
{
    if (a.Substring(a.IndexOf("<div")).Contains("class=\"gg200x300\""))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.Remove(a.IndexOf("<div"),a.IndexOf("</div>")-1)); 
        //output xxxxxxxyyyyyy
    }
}
```

I would not use a regex for this as it will be overly complicated for what you are really looking for and might create false positives unless very specific. It is simple enough to look for a div of a certain class and remove that.

Comment: must replace according iframe,so the regular express "<div[^>]+><iframe[^>]+></iframe></div>"  can work fine.